# Count instances of term in .each

Tags: jquery

I have this code that compares values from one table to another and adds a class if it exists, and that part works.  What I want to do now is show how many times the value exists.  I tried incremental count++ but the numbers are off.

```
function reporgs() {
  jQuery('#attendee01 tr:visible').each(function() {
 var count=0;
    var row = jQuery(this);
    var left_cols = jQuery(this).find("td:nth-child(3)");

    jQuery('#org01 tr').each(function() {

      var right_cols = jQuery(this).find("td:nth-child(1)");
      if (left_cols.html() == right_cols.html()) {
          count++;
        right_cols.css('color', 'red');
        right_cols.append(" <b>" + count + "</b>");
      }
    });
  });
}
```

See the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zjsLqxwp/1/

Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a more simple approach? Maybe just use a selector to match the elements and let Javascript count the occurrences for you.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#org01 td").each(function() {
    var length = jQuery("#attendee01 td:contains(" + jQuery(this).html() + ")").length;
    if (length > 0) {
        jQuery(this).css("color","red");
        jQuery(this).append(" " + length);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Works great - awesome! Accepted

Comment: You should check the contains-selector if it works for all possibilities you need.

Answer (score 0):

You have the loops nested incorrectly. Your approach should be to loop through the orgs, and for each org tally how many attendees there are:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  reporgs();
  //find represented sponsors
  function reporgs() {
    jQuery('#org01 tr').each(function() {
      var count=0;
      var right_cols = jQuery(this).find("td:nth-child(1)");
      jQuery('#attendee01 tr:visible').each(function() {
        var row = jQuery(this);
          var left_cols = jQuery(this).find("td:nth-child(3)");
        if (left_cols.html() == right_cols.html()) {
          count++;
        }
      });
      right_cols.css('color', 'red');
      right_cols.append(" <b>" + count + "</b>");
    });
  }
});
```

However, this is not the most efficient approach, since you're looping through `n` attendees for every `m` orgs, making the time complexity `O(n*m)`. You can instead make this linear by looping through the attendees just once, while tallying the total org count. Then, you can loop through the orgs just once and pull out those tallies which have already been calculated:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  const counts = {};
  jQuery('#attendee01 tr:visible').each(function() {
    const org = jQuery(this).find("td:nth-child(3)").text();
    counts[org] = (org in counts) ? (counts[org] + 1) : 1;
  });

  jQuery('#org01 tr').each(function() {
    const right_col = jQuery(this).find("td:nth-child(1)");
    const org = right_col.text();
    const count = counts[org] || 0;
    right_col
      .css('color', 'red')
      .append(" <b>" + count + "</b>");
  });
});
```

Comment: This was close, but all values were marked red.  Went with @ave4496 cuz that worked best.